# A system to undelete useful comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, deleted-comments

Sometimes a good question is deleted because a few people think it adds no value. Sometimes a good answer is deleted because a few people think it is not fit according to them. But there's the option for a mod-flag or an undelete-vote in these cases, most often used after editing the post into good shape.

Sometimes a highly voted comment is deleted because a few people think it should have been an answer. Sometimes a conversational comment is deleted because a few people think it is purely conversational. Sometimes some other comments are deleted because a few people think it should be deleted at any cost.
But there's no flag or an undelete-vote in these cases, and neither the option to edit the comment to let the useful parts stay.

I know that there's no notification upon the deletion of a comment for [reasons like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255141/10251345). But the "big deal" is that some deleted comments do add value to the post either directly or indirectly which a few people might fail to notice. I am also not repeating the comments under that post because it might encourage a fraction of people who disagree with this post to go there and flag those comments that disagree with their perspective (similar incident had happened with me in the past and the "contact us" button handled the situation appropriately). I wonder how many comments have been deleted so far that has had an unnoticed negative impact in this network, and the people behind it never got a second chance to look into it. I would really appreciate a notification upon the deletion of my comments because it will either help me to improve my behavior on the site or I could appeal against the deletion to let useful content stay as long as it is useful.

If enough flags can delete a comment then shouldn't enough flags be able to undelete a comment (maybe after editing, if an apt system was available)? Sometimes, even a single person with comment-deletion privilege could delete it without notice. It may not always be the case that the removal of a comment is justified, so there should be some way to undelete comments. [Appealing on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368426/10251345) might work, but what's so handy when the commentators never know their comment was deleted in the first place? "Contact Us" might work, but is it guaranteed to be democratic and feasible?

Most comments are added for a good reason. If enough flags counter the "good reason", let the poster be notified and rectify themselves apart from deleting it straightaway. And if those "enough flags" could be countered by other flags for a good cause, which I'm requesting here, what stops it from doing so?

This is a feature request of a system, open for discussion, for all commentators to have a way to know and restore useful comments that could have been / can be deleted in error. There is nothing wrong with making mistakes, but one should always make new ones.

**Edit:-**

If you think that downvoting and deleting my writings will silence my voice, I'm happy to see you wasting your energy and indirectly adding value to this feature request :D

[image]

Comment: *If enough flags can delete a comment* that is only for rude/abusive comments or comments with certain trigger words in it. I'm, pretty sure we don't want to undelete those again, no matter how many undelete flags it gets. If it is important/has value, write an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Comment: In particular, "Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. You should not expect them to be around forever. Once a clarification has been made, an edit added to the post to include new information, or the issue in the comment is otherwise resolved, it can be deleted. Additionally, any comment that violates the comment guidelines listed above is subject to deletion.". The feature request in the current form implies the complete reclassification of comments into something that they currently are not: permanent. And that should be IMHO discussed and decided before this.

Comment: This is impossible. Making it possible would require making deleted comments visible to non-mods and... uh... not going to do that.

Comment: @Tantalus'touch. No problem, if I had the option to edit it then it would look like this: "My question is not focusing on rude comments only, please try to understand the scenario. Notice how I'm not enforcing any system of my own, if you think that rude comments shouldn't be undeleted at any cost then it can be part of the system someone might wish to propose to handle the silent removal of *all types of* comments with respect to the problems mentioned in my post." So, sometimes by deleting a comment in accordance to your existing rules, censors an important point someone is trying to convey.

Comment: @ArdentCoder, some comments are also deleted for a good reason, like a certain number of flags reporting spam, rude, mean or outright unacceptable content.

Comment: @Ollie For example: "I strongly disagree with that. <rude_part>; <disagreeing_reasons>". Here, those reasons are the useful part and they get deleted because of some other part of the comment. I proposed the consideration of an "edit the rude part and flag for undeletion" feature in the post for such comments. This is impossible not because "making it visible to non-mods (which I did not say)" but because there's no notification for the reason of its deletion. uh... not going to do that, there's no need to send notifications as the deletion is always justified, we are the perfect human beings.

Answer (score 15):

No, this doesn't sound as a feature we would need.

> some deleted comments do add value to the post either directly or indirectly which a few people might fail to notice

Well, if comments add value then that value should be moved into the post. If not done by the OP, then by any other user that stumbles upon that comment.

> If enough flags can delete a comment then shouldn't enough flags be able to undelete a comment [...]?

That only goes for rude/abusive comments and comments with one of the trigger words. The rest needs a moderator. We don't want those undeleted at all.

> Sometimes, even a single person with comment-deletion privilege could delete it without notice.

Yes, at 15 rep, anyone can flag and recently OP's got that privilege on their own posts without a reputation barrier. One flag is enough in some cases to nuke it from orbit. Everything is geared to remove more comments, not less.

> Most comments are added for a good reason.

That is true. But a lot of commenters have different definitions of "good". The goal of a comment should be to either ask for clarification, point out an issue or propose improvements you're unsure of adding yourself.

> Let the poster be notified and rectify themselves apart from deleting it straightaway

That leaves the option open to not rectify themselves and leave the comment as is. That sounds highly sub-optimal.

Let me add an observation [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija) made in a comment:

> This is impossible. Making it possible would require making deleted comments visible to non-mods and... uh... not going to do that

I support this as well. While the feature request itself might seem beneficial to the user that had their comments deleted, implementing the feature would open so many cans of worms that for that reason alone we should not push on with this feature.

**TL;DR**

Comments are given way too much value already and some users somehow get emotional attached to it. That never has been the design goal of comments. I like to remind y'll that in the early design stages the Comment option wasn't even considered. In hindsight I value that idea but I agree it was not feasible in practice to do without comments. Use comments were they are meant for. That would prevent having "valuable" comments removed as their value is captured in the post.

If anything, maybe in the flag comment dialog a sentence could be added: *Are you sure any value in this comment is captured in the post?*. Then at least we once again ask flaggers to use this option responsible, if non responsible use is actually a concern.